# How to send function progress to html progressbar using FastAPI jinja2 templates

Tags: python, html, progress-bar, fastapi

I have some function, which can be running for a continuous period of time, I run it using FastAPI background tast like that:

```
background_tasks.add_task(my_func)
```

after that returning template with progressbar using

```
return templates.TemplateResponse('progressbar.html', context={"request": request})
```

How can I define the length of a progressbar iteration and send values to show progress?
`progressbar.html:`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload data</title>
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', path='/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', path='/progressbar.css') }}" rel="progressbar">
</head>
<body>
    <a>Uploading</a>
    <div>
        <progress id="progressbar"></progress>
    </div>
    <form action="/final" method="get" >
        <h1>    
            <input type="submit" value="Start upload">    
        </h1>
        </a>
    </form>
    <p>Return to home page <a href="/">home page</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```